# How to install specific subpackages from package

Tags: pip

I have a package like so;

```
-files
-setup.py
 - utils:
    -__init__.py
    -other files
 - graphics:
    -__init__.py
    -other files
```

And in setup.py I have 'packages=["utils", "graphics"]'

And if I pip install this package, it will install install the utils and graphics folders into the site-packages directory separately.

But what command would I need to run to install JUST the graphics folder and not utils?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No way, sorry. You can install a distribution with or without dependencies, with some optional additions called "extras", you can uninstall an installed distribution, but a distribution can only be installed or uninstalled as a whole, there is no way to install or uninstall a part of a distribution. (To be continued…)

Comment: (…continue) If you want to be able to install parts of your project separately you need to split it into separate distributions. Either completely independent top-level distributions or namespace packages. Read about namespace packages at SO ([tag:namespace-package]) or [Internet search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=python+namespace+packages).